# Why my .php web-page background color didn't change even though I changed the background-color attribute in the CSS style sheet?

Tags: php, css, background-color

I have a home.php file, and a styleSheet.css file that are collocated in the same directory level. In the .css file, I used to have the following background color defined:

```
body {
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
```

And with

```
<link rel="styleSheet" href="./styleSheet.css">
```

in the home.php, the correct color appeared in the home.php home page. Later, I wanted to change the color to a different one:

```
body {
    background-color: #8e3672;
}
```

But the background color in the home page remains as before. I right-clicked on the page, go to View Page Source, and clicked the link in the source file that opened styleSheet.css, and in it I saw the backgrond-color was still #b0e0e6.

I've verified my home.php code to make sure no other place in it defines the background-color (I understand that with CSS, there's a precedence, depending on where the CSS attributes are defined). Also, I refreshed the web page to no avail. So this is pretty weird to me.

Comment: Do a CTRL+F5 to refresh the browsers cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue this fixed it.

If you are using chrome than right click on reload button and select hard reload, this should fix the problem or if you are using Firefox just use Ctrl + F5.

If still problem exists than clear the history :

1. on chrome select "Advanced" and select every option and clear it, reopen the browser and load your page, this should fix it.
2. In Firefox press Ctrl + Shift + Delete and in "Time range to clear:" select "Everything".

Comment: Thanks you guys. Indeed I was using Chrome and Geeky's way of clearing all the history/cache did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your browser is caching an old version of your css file.

In home.php file change the line that creates the stylesheet to include a random timestamp forcing the browser to reload it.  For example:

```
<link rel="styleSheet" href="./styleSheet.css?t=<?php echo round(microtime(true)*1000);?>">
```

I would suggest you think carefully about whether this is needed once your page goes into production.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because of browser cache.
Try to flush it (ctrl + shift + i in Chrome, Network tab, check "Disable cache" and refresh the page).